# How to keep dtype in 0-dim array arithmetics in Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```py
import numpy as np
x=np.array(2, dtype=np.float32)
y=x+1
print(y.dtype)
# float64
```

As shown above, `x` is a 0D array and its dtype is float32. But if you add 1 to it, the output `y` will be float64.

This only happens when x is 0D array. I'm aware to use fcns such as `y=np.add(x,1, dtype=np.float32)` but this will be too tedious for something like `y=(x+1)*3-2`. Is there a way to disable this feature in numpy?

Comment: Note that the result is a `np.float64`, not a 0d array.  Print `x` to see the difference.   The distinction is subtile, but real.

Comment: The result of that math is not a another numpy array, but a numpy scalar, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html.    With `+1`, the python number is converted to something like a `np.int64` or `np.float64`.  Evidently regular dtype precedence rules don't apply, and I don't think you can change them.

Comment: But why are you worried about getting a `np.float64` scalar instead of a `32`?   Choosing '32' over '64' makes some sense when working with really large arrays and memory is a concern, but not when working with single element arrays and scalars.

Comment: A new SO on a similar topic references a NP50, https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0050-scalar-promotion.html, which talks about current handling of scalar arrays.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76117727/what-are-the-rules-for-the-result-dtype-in-arithmetic-operations-of-np-arrays-wi

Comment: @hpaulj really appreciates the link to NEP50. It works now in numpy 1.24. This is a very convenient feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `y` the same `dtype` as `x` when adding `1` to it:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(2, dtype=np.float32)
y = (x + 1).astype(x.dtype)
```

`print(y.dtype)` outputs:

```
float32
```

or in your other example:

```
y = ((x + 1)*3 - 2).astype(x.dtype)
```

or if you find it too tedious to assign `y` `x`'s `dtype` in the same line:

```
y = (x + 1)*3 - 2
y = y.astype(x.dtype)
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable this behavior and force NumPy to use the lower precision data type, you can use the `dtype` parameter when defining the array:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(2, dtype=np.float32)
y = np.array(1, dtype=np.float32)
z = x + y
print(z.dtype)
```