# What are the rules for the result dtype in arithmetic operations of np.arrays with different dtypes?

Tags: python, numpy

Using NumPy I do this operation:

```
x = np.array([1, 2], dtype=np.float16)
y = np.array(1, dtype=np.float32)
z = x * y
print(z.dtype)
```

and the result is

> float16

But, when I switch the data types as below:

```
x = np.array([1, 2], dtype=np.float32)
y = np.array(1, dtype=np.float16)
z = x * y
print(z.dtype)
```

The result is

> float32

And same happens with PyTorch:

```
xt = torch.tensor([1, 2], dtype=torch.float16)
yt = torch.tensor(1, dtype=torch.float32)
zt = xt * yt
print(zt.dtype)
```

the result is

> float16

```
xt = torch.tensor([1, 2], dtype=torch.float32)
yt = torch.tensor(1, dtype=torch.float16)
zt = xt * yt
print(zt.dtype)
```

The result is

> float32

I thought it should be cast to higher precision always. Can anyone explain to me why this is so?

Comment: Apparently it's the type of the first operand?!

Comment: No actually, I have switched the orders and getting same results. It looks like it is tracking the vector's data type, not the scalar.

Comment: Don't want to create an answer because it's only a link answer, but this is the official documentation explaining in part what's going on: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html#numpy.result_type

Comment: Worth looking at [scalar promotion](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0050-scalar-promotion.html) as well since in your example one array is just scalar